# How to deal with multipage registrations in ASP.NET Core 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I created a registration page what I did was have this as my first form action

```
public IActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel registerViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (!_context.users.Any(u => u.Email == registerViewModel.User.Email))
        {
            User user = new User
                    {
                        firstName = registerViewModel.User.firstName,

                      ...some more data
                    };

            _context.users.Add(user);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            // because we the id is 0 in our object whether it's not like that in the database
            registerViewModel.User = _context.users.Where(u => u.Email == user.Email).FirstOrDefault();
            registerViewModel.gyms = _context.gyms.ToList();

            return View("~/Views/Account/Register2.cshtml", registerViewModel);
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "this email is taken");
    }

    return View(registerViewModel);
}
```

and then on my 2nd register page, I added a hidden tap like:

```
<input type="text" value="@Model.User.UserID" asp-for="User.UserID" style="display:none" />
```

and after this

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Register2(RegisterViewModel registerViewModel)
{
    if (true)   // IF MODELSTATE VALID RETURNS TRUE
    {
        User user = _context.users.Find(registerViewModel.User.UserID);
                .., some more data

        registerViewModel.User = user;
        registerViewModel.gym = _context.users.Include("gym").Where(u => u.UserID == user.UserID).FirstOrDefault().gym;

        _context.SaveChanges();

        return View("~/Views/Account/Register3.cshtml", registerViewModel);
    }
    else
    {
        registerViewModel.gyms = _context.gyms.ToList();
        return View(registerViewModel);
    }
}
```

Basically I just send the `UserID` with a model and I take it back every time since the model has the `userID` but the form asp-for model does not.

This works but I have 2 problems with this

1. It feels wrong and not secure, what's the correct way to do this?
2. Why do my 2nd and 3rd page return false for `ModelStateValid`? The id has only these annotations:

```
[Key]
[Required]
```

Comment: Could you share your models?Also,set breakpoints to debug your code and show us the error message in ModelState.

Comment: You could use a hidden field rather than using styles to hide an input. And you could encrypt it so that the value is not easily tampered with.

Comment: Any particular reason not to use Ajax and one controller action instead of for controller actions for each step?